# How to sort array value using the key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i need one help.i am sorting array using the key value,i need if one key value will same then it should come in alphabetically order again.Let me to explain my code below.

```
{"data":[
    {"subcat_id":"9","subcat_name":"SUSHI","order":"9"},
    {"subcat_id":"20","subcat_name":"APPETIZERS","order":"6"},
    {"subcat_id":"6","subcat_name":"CHINESE","order":"4"},
    {"subcat_id":"26","subcat_name":"BRUNCH","order":"4"},
    {"subcat_id":"17","subcat_name":"ENTREES","order":"3"},
    {"subcat_id":"25","subcat_name":"HAPPY HOUR","order":"2"}
]}
```

here if order value will same (`lets say-order->4`),then it should come the alphabetically as per `subcat_name`(`BRUNCH,CHINESE`) like this.

Comment: No,its like if in an array order value is same it should check the alphabetical subcat_name and sort it.

Comment: check multisort() to sort multiple.

Comment: can you edit your answer please?

Comment: basically you can do it with `sort`, you have to pass to it the function which executes the test.

Answer (score 0):

You must create groups by order id and then sort them.

```
$json = '{"data":[
    {"subcat_id":"9","subcat_name":"SUSHI","order":"9"},
    {"subcat_id":"20","subcat_name":"APPETIZERS","order":"6"},
    {"subcat_id":"6","subcat_name":"CHINESE","order":"4"},
    {"subcat_id":"26","subcat_name":"BRUNCH","order":"4"},
    {"subcat_id":"17","subcat_name":"ENTREES","order":"3"},
    {"subcat_id":"25","subcat_name":"HAPPY HOUR","order":"2"}
]}';

$data = json_decode($json);

$ordersGroups = array();
foreach ($data->data as $orderData) {
    if (!isset($ordersGroups[$orderData->order])) {
        $ordersGroups[$orderData->order] = array($orderData);
    } else {
        $ordersGroups[$orderData->order][] = $orderData;
    }
}

$ordersGroups = array_map(function ($orders) {
    usort($orders, function ($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a->subcat_name, $b->subcat_name);
    });
    return $orders;
}, $ordersGroups);

$data->data = array_reduce($ordersGroups, function ($carry, $orderGroup) {
    return array_merge($carry, $orderGroup);
}, array());

$json = json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
$array = //decode your JSON as an array here

$innerComparison = function ($v1, $v2) {
       return strcmp($v1["subcat_name"],$v2["subcat_name"]);
};   

$mainComparison = function ($v1, $v2) use ($innerComparison)  {
       if ($v1["order"] === $v2["order"]) {
             return $innerComparison($v1,$v2);
       } else {
          return $v1["order"] < $v2["order"]:-1:1; 
       }

};

usort($array["data"], $mainComparison);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `usort()`. Assuming your data is stored in the `$obj` object:

```
usort
(
    $obj->data,
    function( $a, $b )
    {
        if( $a->order == $b->order ) return strcmp( $a->subcat_name, $b->subcat_name );
        return $a->order - $b->order;
    }
);
```

above function sort `$obj->data` according to your request.

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/545111)**</kbd>

`usort()` sort an array using a custom function, that receive two elements of array as arguments: the returned function value must be an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

In your case, if `->order` keys are equals, we use `strcmp()` to return sort value based on `->subcat_name`, otherwise we return the difference between two `->order` values.

---

- Read more about [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
- Read more about [strcmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)